# New 14.04 i386 desktop with 3ware 9500s and 4TB RAID, can't partition

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, raid

My install was a bit troublesome but I have most things sorted out.  The main reason I moved this system from XP to Linux was to get support for my upgraded 4TB raid array (old was 2tb).  Both GParted and the Disk utillity fail with not much info.  Other than "failed to create empty partition".  I tried all available types including ext options.  Same error.

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you post the output of this command: `sudo parted -l` (note `parted`, no `g`).  Please issue this command in the terminal and copy and paste the text into your question.  Then Put one backtick ( ` ) at the beginning of the first line, and one at the end of the last line.  Post a comment here when you're done.  Thanks!

Comment: The other system has no access to the internet so pasting that long output here is not easy.  Can you tell me what to look for?    I do see "Disk /dev/sdb: 4500GB" Sector size 512b/512b   partition table : gpt      I just set the table to gpt based on the other response.  Not sure what it was before.

Comment: Is it hardware or software RAID?  Have you got a thumb drive?  How did you "move" the system from Windows to Linux?

Comment: I installed a new OS drive and am keeping the old Windows OS drive as a backup.  I am adding the info for clarity.  I have solved my problems related to disk creation (see my solution post) and a whole host of Samba cfg issues.  It would be great to see more "ground up" builds docs for Ubuntu.  I found none and still have several unrelated issues to resolve.

Comment: It is hardware RAID.  The 9500 controller is automatically recognized by Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

`Try` the LiveCD version of Ubuntu from a DVD or USB

`Open` a terminal.

Identify the device names for your hard drives, `type`:

```
sudo -i
fdisk -l
```

Suppose their hard drivers were `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdb`.

Then create the partition on each drive.

The partition table needs to be GPT to allow more than 2TB to be used.

Type:

```
parted /dev/sda
```

At the parted prompt, create the partition table, type:

```
mklabel gpt
```

Then type to quit:

```
q
```

Type:

```
parted /dev/sdb
```

At the parted prompt, create the partition table, type:

```
mklabel gpt
```

Then type to quit:

```
q
```

Now install Ubuntu via the GUI.

Select `Manual` as your partition method

Select your hard drive, and agree `to Create a new empty partition table on this device ?`

Select the `Free Space` on the 1st drive then select `automatically partition the free space`

Ubuntu will create two partitions, `/` (root) & `swap`

On `/` (root) partition select `bootable flag` and set it to `on`

**Repeat steps for the other hard drive**

Now select `Configure Software RAID`

Select `Yes`

Select `Create new MD drive`

Select RAID type: `RAID 0` or `RAID 1`.  RAID 0 and 1 need 2 drives.

Number of spare devices. Enter 0 if you have no spare drive.

Select which partitions to use..

Repeat steps with each pair of partitions you have created.

Filesystem and mount points will need to be specified for each RAID device. By default they are set to `do not use`.

Once done, select `finish`.

Open a terminal

Type:

```
sudo -i
grub-install /dev/sda
grub-install /dev/sdb
update-initramfs -k all -u
```

Comment: Sorry, my original information was not clear enough.  The installation of Ubuntu is complete on the boot drive.  That drive is partitioned and fine.  The sdb drive is my problem.  How do I manually partition it and format it for use?  I am now assuming that it needs to be GPT which is not an option in either of the gui utilities.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I mainly needed to use parted to make it a GPT partition.  It seems simply ridiculous to me that neither Disks nor any other gui utility I tried had that option, much less defaulted to it after recognizing that it was a 4TB aray.    Not to mention the unfixed "show in user interface" bug in Disks that cost me many more hours trying to mount the disks.   Honestly, if XP supported >2TB partitions, I would have gone back to it days ago.  This process was pretty painful and the help docs are all over the place leading to many dead ends.  I wish I knew how to help clean this all up.